# TZupdater broke JRE update

Tags: java

After manually install new version of Olson timezone DB (2011h) broke update JRE

Now, I cant install update to 6u29, while updating shows message:
lib/zi/Asia/Anadyr: Old file not found. However, a file of the same name was found.
 No update done since file contens do not match.

Anybody know how fix this problem without uninstall previos version (users don't have access to do this)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that TZUpdater creates a backup of the previous timezone information

e.g.`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\zi.tzdata2011g`

To revert back to previous timezone data, delete the current zi directory then rename the backup zi directory (e.g. `zi.tzdata2011g`) to `zi`.

This is how I was able to recover from a corrupt `TZUpdate` once upon a time

Once you have the old timezone information, your update should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/old_files.xml

http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/fpupdater-tool-readme-305936.html 
Windows

On Windows based systems, patching the system may take several minutes.

If Auto-Update is run on a JRE on which FPUpdater, has been applied, the installation of that update will fail. The download will take place as normal. Then the user will see a series of error messages.
Warning: lib/rt.jar: Old File not found. However, a file of the same name was found. No update done since file contents do not match.
Error: Java(TM) Update fails to apply changes to your system.
Java Setup: Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
Java Setup: Installation Failed

To resolve this, the Offline installer should be downloaded and installed. If a release prior to 6u24 is installed, the FPUpdater tool will need to be run again to patch the newly installed JRE.